# Can't install extensions on site, GNOME SHELL 3.6

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

Can't install extensions. I just slide from "off" to "on" and nothing happens. Using Gnome Shell 3.6 on ubuntu 12.10 while browsing on google chrome. Tried to install on epiphany and firefox. Same issue.

Comment: in about:plugins appear gnome shell plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

just a guess..
but maybe the the proxy settings were set?

I've got the same problem
i had set a proxy in the gnome-networksettings couse i need them at work
but overwrite them with the firefox-settings.

After i disabled the proxy the firefox plugin worked fine again.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a wild stab in the dark: If you're using Chrome/Chromium, navigate to about:plugins and make sure "Gnome Shell Integration" is enabled. Then navigate back to extensions.gnome.org and when the ribbon appears at the top make sure you "Always Allow for this Site"

On Firefox you'll have to do something similar if you've turned extensions off. Browse to about:plugins and make sure libgnome-shell-browser-plugin.so is present / enabled. If it's not, upgrade Gnome Shell, or find it on your filesystem and link to it from to ~/.mozilla/plugins (you shouldn't have to do this though).